# I am trying to open a new activity by clicking on a image in a gridview in one fragment but I facing some problem

Tags: android

I am trying to open a new activity for a image when I am clicking on a image in a gridview in a fragment.

This is the code for fragment gallery:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_frag_gallery, container, false);

        list=imageReader(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory());

        gv=v.findViewById(R.id.gridView);
        gv.setAdapter(new GridAdapter());

        gv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                startActivity(new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),galWal.class).putExtra("img",list.get(position)));
            }
        });



        return v;
    }
```

This is the code for the new activity

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_gal_wal);

        String f = getIntent().getStringExtra("img");
        iv2=findViewById(R.id.imgView);

        iv2.setImageURI(Uri.parse(f));
    }
```

This is the xml file for the new activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".galWal">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/imgView"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View view, int position, long id) 
           {
                Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this, fullScreen.class);
                intent.putExtra("image", arrayList.get(position).getmThumbIds());
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

If you still face the problem, you can visit 
https://11zon.com/android/android_gridview.php

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:

```
startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), galWal.class).putExtra("img",list.get(position)));
```

Comment: can you please help me in writing the code for the galWal.class activity

Comment: @KoushikBiswas yes, if it simple